# Software to view and recenter world map seen in rectangular and two-circle views

Tags: android, geography, android-app

I'm looking for an interactive Android software that displays, the map of the world in two formats.

At the top, a rectangular view.

At the bottom, a spherical view, consisting of two circles, each denoting a one half of the sphere.

At the bottom, a point can be dragged, across the two circles, or, even at the top, across the rectangle (the two points are synchronized). When the point is dragged, it can be turned into the "north pole" of the sphere by pressing a button found beneath these two maps (which says "Turn point into maps' virtual north pole").

When the button is clicked, the selected "north pole" becomes the center of the sphere on the right the sphere at the left is the remaining part of the world, and the rectangular part at the top becomes the map of the world as drawn centered about this "new north pole".

Each time this is done, the view of all three maps (rectangle, and two circles denoting the two sphere halves projected onto the circle where the sphere is cut), should change significantly.

On the rectangle, the "new north pole", and corresponding "new south pole", become topologically identified with the top and bottom sides of the rectangle, respectively.

Where can I find such software?

Thanks.